# Can't load my current user's posts from Firebase - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to load my current user's posts from my Firebase Database.

This is my database's architecture:
[image]
I have already successfully loaded all the posts into a home view but when I tried to duplicate and use the same method here with the necessary changes and using the uid for the current user's posts, it's not showing anything... Have run out of ideas as to what the problem might be, could use some help.

Here's a screenshot from the ProfileUserPosts swift file:
[image]

```
    //VARS
    var postsuser = [ProfileUserPosts]()    

@objc func observeUserPosts() {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("author")
         postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userid").queryEqual(toValue: uid!).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

            var tempPost = [ProfileUserPosts]()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot {

                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]

                    //Post Picture
                    let photoUrl = dict!["photoUrl"] as? String
                    let url = URL(string: photoUrl!)

                    //Info Post
                    let comments = dict!["comments"] as? String
                    let city = dict!["city"] as? String
                    let municipality = dict!["municipality"] as? String
                    let breed = dict!["breed"] as? String
                    let phoneuser = dict!["phone"] as? String
                    let postType = dict!["postType"] as? String
                    let petType = dict!["petType"] as? String
                    let gender = dict!["gender"] as? String
                    let timestampadoption = dict!["timestamp"] as? Double
                    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestampadoption!/1000)

                    let post = ProfileUserPosts(breed: breed!, phone: phoneuser!, photoUrl: url!, city: city!, municipality: municipality!, petType: petType!, gender: gender!, timestamp: date, postType: postType!, comments: comments!)

                    tempPost.insert(post, at: 0)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.postsuser = tempPost
                    self.postsCollectionView.reloadData()
                    self.refresher.endRefreshing()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's where I'm loading the CollectionView with the numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItem

```
extension ProfileViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return postsuser.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: PostsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postsCell", for: indexPath) as! PostsCollectionViewCell

        cell.set(post: postsuser[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my guess - based on your database structure - is that you're accessing an invalid path.
When you've referenced `Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("author")`, you're saying that `posts` have a direct child to `author` and that's not true, they've a direct child of a `post id`, which then fetching the respective `post`, you can get the `author`, so in this case, you would've to iterate through all the posts.

So, to fetch all the posts:

`let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")`

then you would have an **Object** (**very important** **- this is not an array**) of posts with ID's as keys, then you would iterate through them and fetch the respective author you want. I won't get into details of your implementation, but just to clarify what I'm saying:

`let specificPostAuthor = postsRef.child("LOj1UZZgUnKa28xVtht").child("author")`

would return the **respective post author**.

Comment: I'm sorry Guilherme, I'm self taught at coding and still quite new at it, I didn't comprehend much your reply, could you further explain :) ....

Comment: Sure, I'll try to reformulate my answer, but first it would be nice to know what does your `(snapshot)` returns, so I don't mess it up an answer here

Comment: I actually don't see any snapshot :o